# Load an URL into a webview from outside the application does not work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, http, webview, httphandler

I'm trying to load an URL into a webview from outside the application. I've set my info.plist properly to support http, https. My app appear in the handler list (safari preference pan). 
Here is my code

I have this in my awakefromnib

```
        NSAppleEventManager *em = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];
    [em 
     setEventHandler:self 
     andSelector:@selector(getUrl:withReplyEvent:) 
     forEventClass:kInternetEventClass 
     andEventID:kAEGetURL];
```

And then

```
//get the URL from outside the application
- (void)getUrl:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event 
withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
{

    // Get the URL
    NSString *urlStr = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] 
                        stringValue];

    [self initWithUrl:urlStr]; 
}

//Can be used as intializer to init the webview with a page
-(void)initWithUrl:(NSString *)url
{
    //load the lading home page
    [[webview mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];



}
```

If i nslog the url it show it (so it properly get it). My next method is also called. This method work fine from inside my app.

The problem is that when I click in a link outside of my app (once the app is selected as default browser). I popup the window but it not load the URL. It just does nothing.
Any idea ?

Comment: And what is the problem? Any errors, what behaviour is happening and what did you expect?

Comment: Wow sorry, Yeah I've forgotten the problem. So clicking on an URL outside of the browser open it but the webiew just not load the URL.

Answer (score 0):

What is the "mainFrame" method of webview?  Is that a custom class?  Did you add the web view's frame to the window's frame?

Comment: I just took the example in the Apple document which consist of loading the desired URL in the main frame of the webview object:

Comment: Hardcode some basic html such as setting the body background to red and see if that shows up.  Then you'll know if it's loading the webView but not the url, or if it's not even loading the webView.